# how to update fields of primary key using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to update some fields of a primary key of table in some instances when using spring data `jpa.Im` using save method of the jpa repository to persist the changes, when changed columns include part of the primary key it gives an exception.

i'm currently getting following exception when the updated files include a column from `primary key`.

`org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`

is there a way to safely update the primary key fields.

Comment: Could you please add the code snippet you tried

Comment: Why are you trying to change the primary key of a database record? The general definition of the primary key is "the identifying property that doesn't change".

Comment: @chrylis in an edit function i'm supposed to allow the user to edit the primary key columns as well.

Comment: "is there a way to safely update the primary key fields?" answer is no.

Comment: The answer is "you don't". PKs are supposed to be immutable. If you used purely technical, auto-generated IDs as recommended, nobody would care about changing the ID of the entities.

Comment: My application do not have complete ownership of this table, we are doing the edits and insertions, another application is querying the table, so changing the primary keys is not the desired solution.

Comment: Depends on mapping, how do you map with JPA. Most of the time we do not require to update the pkeys and insert ware made automatically through ORM mapping. And also why do you want to solve anomaly with the system? You can do it on your premises. Alos your application do not have complete ownership of this table, then you may not be allowed to do this too

Answer (score 0):

If pk is changed, what happens with foreign, you need replicate this change on children tables? Anyway, if you need to change pk values inside hibernate you must add one id column unique, mapping this as property id instead of real pk without change the real pk. But never change pk is a good idea.

Comment: there aren't any foreign key relationships depending on the changed fields

Answer (score 0):

Forget about modifying the value of a primary key. Just because each modification also implies modifying foreign key values.

But there is way to fix this situation:

- Convert the current primary key into a **unique** key.
- Add a numeric or uuid column, containing a generated, technical (i.e. non-business) primary key.
- Unfortunately you have to update all dependents table (schema and values) so that they point to new primary key. But this has to be done once, when the database is offline.

This way it should be transparent to the other application querying the table, its query won't change.